# why my menu site links doesn't work?

Tags: jquery, html, menu, megamenu

i have a problem with my menu . links on it doesn't work
it seems to links have interfere with j query
how can i fix this? 
my site link: http://ariaweblab.ir

```
        <div class="MegaMenu14">


            <div id="menu-wrapper">

                <ul class="nav">

                    <li><a href="Default.aspx">صفحه اصلی</a></li>


                    <li>
                        <a href="#">درباره آریاوب</a>
                        <div style="width: 400px; right: 0;">




                            <div class="nav-column2">
                                <div class="imginMega2">
                                    <span id="Label13">18</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="nav-column">
                                <h3 class="orange">منوی اصلی</h3>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="Fa_pages_details.aspx?PageID=25&sBar=26">افتخارات  </a></li>
                                    <li><a href="Fa_pages_details.aspx?PageID=27&sBar=28">رزومه </a></li>
                                    <li><a href="Fa_pages_details.aspx?PageID=29&sBar=30">اهداف آریاوب</a></li>

                                    <li><a href="Fa_pages_details.aspx?PageID=33&sBar=34">پیام مدیریت</a></li>

                                </ul>
                            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your links are not interfering with jquery but code on your scripts.js does, fix the code on line 169 `event.preventDefault();` line will stop the browser from redirecting to next page. If you need that click event write a specific selector